# Unexpected JAXRPC endpoint, this version is not supported 1.1

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, jax-rpc

I'm trying to compile a webservice through NetBeans 6.7 using Glassfish v3 as the host is there anyway to fix this issue:

```
'Unexpected JAXRPC endpoint, this version is not supported 1.1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it may be a bug in Glassfish:

https://glassfish.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=7003

Comment: I ended up switching to Tomcat, and its running the app nicely. However Tomcat isn't playing very nice with netbeans. [I have a separate question for that open]